# using <a href> for a mysqli select statement

Tags: php, mysqli, href

could someone please direct me to a simple (basic easy) tutorial or resource page of how to use hyperlinks in a website to display the results of a select statement

To be precise - I am working on the footer section of my website http://www.mandyevansartist.com 
when someone clicks on the words 'coloured pencils' I would like them to be taken to the catagory.php page and be shown an array from the database

I know this is possible because I already have made it work by clicking an image - (there is an area in the http://www.mandyevansartist.com/gallery.php page that says 'click on a picture to see others in that catagory')

I have achieved this by

```
    <?php
session_start();
include 'header.php';
echo '<h1>CLICK ON AN IMAGE TO SEE OTHERS IN THAT CATAGORY</h1>';
$con = mysqli_connect("*","*","*","*");
$db = mysqli_select_db("images", $con);

$answer = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT image FROM images where HEAD = 'true'");
echo '<div id = "list">';
echo '<ul>'; 
    while   ($row   =   mysqli_fetch_array($answer))    {
    $pic = $row[image];
    $link ="<a href = 'catagory.php?id=".$row[image]."'>" . ' <img src="'.$pic.'" style ="height:222px;"/> '. "</a>";
echo '<li>' .$link.'</li>';  
    }
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

At this point my footer.php is mainly html (enclosed in an echo'') with links going to nowhere

```
    <div id="footer-one">
<h1>GALLERY</h1>
<p><a href = "#" >people pictures</a></p>
<p><a href = "#" >romance</a></p>
<p><a href = "#" >seascapes</a></p>
<p><a href = "#" >under the ocean</a></p>
<p><a href = "#" >paintings</a></p>
<p><a href = "#" >love heart series</a></p>
<p><a href = "#" >new works</a></p>
</div><!--/footer-one-->
```

one of the ways I have tried to insert a mysqli query into it

```
        <h1>GALLERY</h1>';
 $answer=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT image FROM images WHERE catagory =    pencils");
 while ($answer2 = mysqli_fetch_array($answer));    
 $link = <p><a href = "catagory.php?id=$answer2">family portraits</a></p>
 echo '<p>' .$link.'</p>';
 echo' <p><a href = "#" >coloured pencils</a></p>
```

which just comes up with a parse error - unexpected "<"

I am looking for a tutorial to guide me through this process because i have looked and looked and cant find one

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. here we expect you to have a go at it yourself before asking for help. You can google for tutorials fairly easily. Or just have a bash - imagine how you'd write it if you happened to be the god of php and you could make it work however seems most sensible. Write that down. Then, look up each of the pieces in your php resource (or google for one). When you've done as much as you can and it's still breaking, come back and show us what you tried, and the error that you are getting.

Comment: Hi Taryn, and thanks for the response. Being a tad ocd with the coding I have tried hundreds of different possibilities and have broken down code that works in a similar way almost word by word - I have googled multitudes of variations of ways to ask the question. I know this is simple and so as a last resort i have asked the question here in the hope that someone could direct me to a tutorial- the reason I have worded the code as I have is too explain what I am trying to do in a clear manner

Comment: unfortunately it's not clear to me what you're trying to do. I think you have implied knowledge about what you're trying to do :)
If you can edit your question and share with us the best example of what you thought should work (but didn't), that would help us to help you better - add it as an example to your actual question (along with the error message or bad data you got). Note: don't put code in comments because the formatting is dreadful :P

Answer (score 1):

The error `parse error - unexpected "<"` is due to some missing stuff like `'`, `"` and `{}`. Try following fixes.

```
<?php 
$answer = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT image FROM images WHERE catagory = pencils");
while ($answer2 = mysqli_fetch_array($answer));
{
    $img = $answer2['image'];
    $link = "<a href = 'catagory.php?id=$img'>family portraits</a></p>";
}
echo '<p>'.$link.'</p>';
echo '<p><a href = "#" >coloured pencils</a></p>';
?>
```

From the given code, I have come up with these fixes. But there may be some changes as per your requirements.

Comment: thank you so much for this effort I am really grateful - it still doesnt recognize the id in the url though. What I really need is a decent tutorial so i can understand how the process works